# How to configure docker proxy repository in Nexus3 for GitLab container registry?

Tags: docker, gitlab, nexus3

I am trying to configure a docker proxy repository in Nexus 3 for docker images hosted in GitLab container registry. I can successfully execute a pull using the following command:

```
docker pull gitlab.masked.url:5443/masked-group/masked-project/masked-image:latest
```

To configure proxy repository in Nexus I use the following settings:

```
Name: dockertest
Format: docker
Type: proxy
Url: https://nexus.masked.url/repository/dockertest/
Online: true
Remote storage: https://gitlab.masked.url:5443
Use certificates stored in the Nexus truststore...: true
Docker index: Use proxy registry (specified above)
HTTP Authentication: true
Authentication type: Username
Username: foo
Password: ***
```

Everything else left to default values. Now if I execute

```
docker pull nexus.masked.url:443/repository/dockertest/masked-group/masked-project/masked-image:latest
```

I get the following response:

```
Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n  <title>404 - Nexus Repository Manager</title>\n...
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: No, we moved to JFrog Artifactory